# JSTL: I need to access hashtable using a key

Tags: jstl

I know this works: `<c:out value="${model.testhash['A']}"/>`

but I need something like: 
    `<c:out value="${model.testhash[${model.testkey}]}"/>`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
${model.testhash[model.testkey]}
```

In general the ${ } only delineates the JSTL expression, you don't need to escape the lookup for the model.testkey lookup as well, so it is also possible to do:

```
${model.testhash[model.condition ? 'A' : 'B']}
```

.. just as an example.