# Associative array in JSP or an alternative

Tags: database, arrays, jsp

In my JSP project, I have a class which contains methods for insertion, selection, etc. An example is `getAllStudents()`. This will select some fields from a table and it has to return that records.

So, I am confused at how to display it in my display page(template). In my display page, I would create an object of this class and call this method to get all student details. But is it possible to return an associative array, like in PHP ? So that, I could store this array returned by the method, and print the elements wherever necessary ?
I mean, it would be easy to output the array elements, if it was an associative array.

Or is there an alternative in JSP ?

Thanks in advance :)

PS: I am new to JSP. I did searched in Google. But no good results were found on "associative array in JSP". So, I am assuming that it is not available in JSP! Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, a HashTable or HashMap is probably the closest match to an associative array (other table or map types work too).

Here is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279949/jstl-i-need-to-access-hashtable-using-a-key) with an example of accessing a hashtable in JSP.

Answer (score 0):

There are no associative arrays, that is something that scripting languages like PHP bring to the table. In PHP, there are no real arrays, instead they use Hashtables, and call them arrays.
Java has a Hashtable map as well. You can use this to store a key/value pair, where the key or value can be of any datatype . This is no good with a JList that wants a scalar collection.

Give the list an object instead. Override the toString on it to only show what data is to be seen. Selection of an object will return an object instead of just the display.
Alternatively you could implement the ListCellRenderer tied to a custom JLabel to show what you want instead. That can be set to the JList by invoking the setCellRenderer method.

here is a good discussion on this http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-227422.html